# MYSQL Subtracting values between rows where the subtracted number is displayed along with the rows from which it is subtracted

Tags: mysql

I have a table like:

| concatenated_dates | mat_emp | rest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EX 2018/2019 | AO-26 | 27.5 |
| EX2019/2020 | AO-26 | 30 |
| EX2020/2021 | AO-26 | 30 |
| EX2021/2022 | AO-26 | 30 |
| EX2022/2023 | AO-26 | 30 |

I want code that would subtract the variable number which in this case is 40, I want it to subtract it from the first "rest" column and it would put how much it subtracted in a new row at the start with the name of "rest-40", and replaces the "rest" value with how much is left from the value (if it's lower than 0 then it would set it as 0), and it would get the remaining number from the subtractet number (40 at start) and subtract if from the next row and use the subtracted value to subtract next row until the remaining is 0 then stop the table there, like the exmple below, I want the same results

| rest-40 | concatenated | mat_emp | rest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27.5 | EX 2018/2019 | AO-26 | 0 |
| 12.5 | EX2019/2020 | AO-26 | 17.5 |

Notice: dont use update becose this is not a table it is a view.

I tried explaining it to chatGpt multiple times and didn't give me any satisfying results, and this is the closest it could get:

```
SELECT 
    LEAST(rest, 40) as subtracted_value,
    concatenated_dates,
    mat_emp,
    GREATEST(rest - 40, 0) as remaining_rest
FROM 
    your_table
WHERE 
    rest > 0;
```

I want it to only subtract 40 from the first row only, and it would subtract the rest of the 40 to the next row and so on the proccess until the result is 0 then it's done

Comment: Provide the output for `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: VERSION: 5.7.44

Comment: You must use user-defined variables. Investigate cumulative sum calculations using UDVs.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a UDV to track the cumulative sum of `rest`:

```sql
SELECT
    IF(40 - cum_sum < 0, 40 - (cum_sum - rest), rest) AS `rest-40`,
    concatenated_dates,
    mat_emp,
    (SELECT rest - `rest-40`) AS rest
FROM (
    SELECT yt1.*, @cum_sum := @cum_sum + rest AS cum_sum
    FROM your_table yt1
    JOIN (SELECT @cum_sum := 0) vars
    ORDER BY concatenated_dates
) AS cumulative
WHERE cum_sum - rest < 40;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT
    LEAST(remaining, rest) AS `rest-40`,
    concatenated_dates,
    mat_emp,
    (SELECT rest - `rest-40`) AS rest
FROM (
    SELECT yt1.*, 40 - @cum_sum AS remaining, @cum_sum := @cum_sum + rest AS cum_sum
    FROM your_table yt1
    JOIN (SELECT @cum_sum := 0) vars
    ORDER BY concatenated_dates
) AS cumulative
WHERE remaining > 0;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qm7y3qow).